# Is it possible to create an audio file based on CSV-data and an existing audio file?

Tags: javascript, audio

I am working on a project in `JavaScript`, and I need to do a fairly strange task. I am not sure how to achieve it. I have looked into the most popular libraries for audio, but it doesn't seem to be an easy way to just export a created file fast, without recording it in real-time. I might be wrong.

I am going to have some data as `JSON` or in `CSV` format with numbers in each row. That number corresponds to seconds elapsed. This data tells me when a certain audio file needs to be played. The audio file is just a 5-second long clip of beeps.

I need to generate a long audio file that is just silent, but where the audio clip plays when "instructed" by the data. So it could play at 10 seconds, 45 seconds, 267 seconds, etc.

The finished audio file could be over an hour long. I was hoping to create a system where I could just select an audio file and a data file from my computer, click a button, let it process, and then download the finished file.

I hope what I want to do is not unclear. Can I use the Web Audio API for this, or do I need a library? I am stuck at the first part of the process, namely what to use and how to "create" a file from nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try *MediaRecorder* from **MediaStream Recording API** - it will let you create a recording function (something like this):

```
const stream = navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true });
const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
// then you can get your number from JSON / CSV file and do next
mediaRecorder.start();
await sleep(YOUR_NUMBER_FROM_FILE);
mediaRecorder.stop();
```

The example above just creates audio that will be last concrete seconds.
You can load your existing files of audio and try it play in the background. I suppose *MediaRecorder* will record them too.
See MDN Web Docs about *MediaRecorder*
To summarize - **Web Audio API** and **MediaStream Recording API** will be enough for your case.
I hope this will help you in some ways.

Comment: Thanks for answering. But will I need to wait the whole hour for this to record in real time? Or will it "render" fast?